# Найти строку в тексте

Tags: c#

Есть текст, в этом тексте есть такая строчка "abracadabra(12345);"
Вопрос в том как найти эту строку в тексте и вытащить из нее числа, в данном примере 12345?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью `Regex`:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"abracadabra\((\d+)\)");

string text = "Тут будет записан разный текст среди которого abracadabra(12345), которую надо вытащить";


var value = regex.Match(text).Groups[1].Value; // =12345
```

Если таких подстрок много то:

```
foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо за ответ. Ваш ответ помог мне.

Comment: А можно спросить про запись @"abracadabra\((\d+)\)". Где я могу почитать о подобных записях?

Comment: Гуглите Регулярные выражения C# =)

Comment: Понял) спс, я на этом сайте недавно и не знаю как тут все работает, может я могу как-то лайкнуть вас за помощь ?

Comment: Ну само принятие ответа уже дает мне балы, но можно еще и голос отдать за ответ. Там слева от ответа над цифрой стрелочка вверх. Комментарии лайкать бессмысленно - ничего не дает комментирующему.

Answer (score 0):

Набрасал на скорую руку, в компиляторе не проверял, но на взгляд должно сработать.

```
string Text = "Тут будет записан разный текст среди которого abracadabra(12345), которую надо вытащить";
string Row = "abracadabra(12345)";
int indexOfRow = Text.IndexOf(Row);
Text = Text.Substring(indexOfRow , indexOfRow+17);
string Row ="";
for (int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(Text[i]))
    {
        Row += Text[i];
    }
}
```

С уважением и удачи.

Comment: Спасибо, что ответили. А если такая ситуация: я знаю, что в тексте точно будет abracadabra(тут числа), но не знаю какие именно там числа, как мне тогда найти строку?

Comment: Количество чисел известно? или это тоже рандомная величина

Comment: Да, рандомная. Мне кажется, что я где-то, когда-то видел подобную запись: abracadabra("тут были какие-то символы, я так понял, что они означали для компилятора, мол не важно что тут написано");.

Comment: Вы видели то что в моем ответе

Comment: Всем спасибо за быстрые ответы, очень помогли!